# Datatable error when data is fetching from server angular js

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatable

Hello I am new to angular JS. I just involved into dataTable in html table. 
but when sometime **$http** takes time to load data from server. then dataTable is throwing some errors. ex. [alert screenshot](https://snag.gy/qXtLsi.jpg) 
and in console there is error is [console screenshot](https://snag.gy/JgeXUI.jpg).
please let me know if you want to know additional details of problem?

**HTML code :**

```
<table datatable="ng" class="table dataTable" dt-options="dtOptions">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>D</th>
        <th>E</th>
        <th>F</th>
        <th>G</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="data in list">
        <td>
           {{data.A}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{data.B}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{data.C}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{data.D}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{data.E}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{data.F}}
        </td>
        <td>
           {{data.G}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Controller Code :**

```
app.controller('AController', ['$scope', '$http', 'DTOptionsBuilder', 'DTColumnBuilder', function($scope, $http, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {

  // DataTables configurable options
  $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withDisplayLength(10)
    .withLanguage({
      "sEmptyTable": "No record found",
    });

  $scope.listData = function() {

    $http({
      url: Api_url,
      method: 'GET',
      data: {},
      headers: $rootScope.headers
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

      $scope.list = data.Params;

    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    });
  };
}]);
```

Comment: please share your code.

Comment: updated with piece of code.

Comment: You must use `$watchCollection`. Your `$http` is Async so your DOM loads and the $http catchup. That is why you get error. `$watchCollection` your `$scope.listData` and they update the view.

Comment: I never use $watchCollection :o . can you examined and modify my code?

Comment: Go to the link provided by the error `https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4`

Comment: Can you post  the data by console.log of the data you are getting from server end?

Comment: here it is.
https://jsonblob.com/57ba9668e4b0dc55a4ef0935